# UI Dropdown - Is it possible to have a custom value type instead of an index?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm using the [UI Dropdown component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Dropdown.html) which lets you set the text of an option (`OptionData`) only.  The value of an option is the index position in the options list, so there is no way to set this.

My problem is that I have a `dictionary<string, tile>` that I use to populate the dropdown options, but I would like the value of the option to be the id of the tile class, not the index position.

---

Edit:

I know I can access elements from the list by using the value (index).

```
list[dropdown.value].id
```

But I wanted to see about extending the dropdown with this small change, as I have some other changes I would like to make, but wanted to start with something simple first just to get an idea of what is possile.

I do not want someone to post a full code solution.  Am mostly after some pointers.  Looking at the dropdown class, I don't see how I can extend it to modify some things (value in this case), it looks like I would have to implement by own version?

---

Some code will make this a little clearer I think:

```
// All tiles into list.
List<Tile> list = new List<Tile>(mydictionary.Values);

// Sort all tiles based on the tile name.
list.Sort((x,y) => x.name.CompareTo(y.name));

// Current way to add list to dropdown.
for(int i=0; i<list.Count; i++){
    dropdown.options.Add(new Dropdown.OptionData(){
        text = list[i].name // Tile name (string).
    }); 
});

// What I want to do.
for(int i=0; i<list.Count; i++){
    dropdown.options.Add(new Dropdown.OptionData(){
        text = list[i].name, // Tile name (string).
        value = list[i].id // Unqiue tile id (string).
    }); 
});

// Getting changed value
dropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate {
    Debug.Log(dropdown.value); // Instead of the index selected, I want the tile id
});
```

Or if the value is needed internally for some reason, then maybe an extra property that can be set and retrieved.

```
for(int i=0; i<list.Count; i++){
    dropdown.options.Add(new Dropdown.OptionData(){
        text = list[i].name, // Tile name (string).
        tile_id = list[i].id // Unqiue tile id (string).
    }); 
});

dropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate {
    Debug.Log(dropdown.tile_id);
});
```

I took a look at the `DropDown` class to see if I could extend it and add the "tile_id" option in, but I got completely lost on what to do, as I am still quite new to C#.

https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/a3f89d5f7d145e4b6fa11cf9f2de768fea2c500f/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Dropdown.cs

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Dropdown.html

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with doing

```
dropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate {
    Debug.Log(list[dropdown.value].id); 
});
```

You can use that id to index into the list you filled the dropdown with.

Comment: Yeah, I know I can do it like that.  But I wanted to see about extending the dropdown class so I didn't need to rely on the list of options for accessing the selected element id.

Comment: Edited my question just to clarify what I am after.  It's more of me learning to extend something than needing it.  However, I don't think I can make the change I want if I am understanding things correctly from looking at the source.